# How to send value to an div which has textbox role

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send a new value to a div which has textbox role and I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError:document.querySelector(...).value is not a function at <anonymous>:1:59
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="msg-form__contenteditable t-14t-black--light t-normal flex-grow-1 full-height notranslate"contenteditable="true" role="textbox"aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Write a message…"> 
<p>
<br>
</p>
</div>
```

**MY CODE**
It finds the element, but it doesn't send the value.

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="Writea message…"]').value("Paul")
```

Comment: Missing a space between "Write" and "a" in the JavaScript. Also, `value()` isn't a valid JS function. You would need to create an element or node for the text and append it to the `<div>`. Or you could replace the content with `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some [light reading on the `textbox` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/textbox_role). Straight from there:

> It is a better practice to use an `<input>` element with type="text", or a `<textarea>` element instead of the ARIA textbox role. When using either semantic element, the ARIA textbox role is not necessary. [See Notes on Using ARIA in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/).

If you're set on using a `<div>`, `value` isn't a valid attribute for it, and you'll need to use `.innerText` or `innerHTML`

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="Write a message…"]').innerHTML = 'Paul';
```

Also: `.value()` isn't a function (that's the error you're receiving). If you're trying to set the value of an element that `value` is a valid attribute for, you'll use `element.value = 'Paul';` with JavaScript, or `element.val('Paul');` with jQuery

Comment: You gave me an idea, and it worked like this by finding the p element using getelementsbytag, and then I changed inner HTML for the paragraph